# Mounting an external drive

Tags: filesystems, mount, hard-disk

So I recently switched back to Pop!_OS(based on Ubuntu, was directly by askUbuntu to come here) and I want to use my external hard drives with it, they're using the NTFS file system.
Previously they were used on Windows (currently not installed) which is why they're mounted at first as ro, I changed my first drive to rw [2].
The content of the terminal:

```
user@pop-os:~$ cat /proc/mounts | grep /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1 /media/user/244DB8D1551F0E54 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
user@pop-os:~$ mkdir /media/user/244DB8D1551F0E54/test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/user/244DB8D1551F0E54/test’: No such file or directory
```

Note:
I'm pretty sure that I did something wrong in the mounting process. Btw there's no chance for me to format the drives, there are crucial data on it, which can't be lost, and I have no way to back the entire drive up. As this would be my only way to not forget some files.

Comment: I think that the reason why Linux wants to mount the file systems read-only is that Windows left them 'dirty'. The standard setting of Windows is 'Fast Startup', which is a kind of semi-hibernation, and the data left in buffers are put into swap space instead of being completely written to their target file systems. If this is the case the quick solution is to start Windows again and 'reboot' instead of shutdown, and the best solution to turn off Fast Startup and then shutdown ...

Comment: ... But now that you have removed Windows, this is not easy, and maybe the best alternative now is to connect the drive via a USB adapter to a working Windows system in another computer and try to repair the file system (a few files might be corrupted, but almost all files will be OK). Then select 'Safely Remove Hardware' and unplug it. Otherwise, if you use Linux tools, there is a risk that a few more files will be damaged, but if you are lucky, things will work well.

Comment: In Linux you can try to mount the drives according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for the explanation, I tried using the link you provided, and  it warned me of exactly that, so thats my case. Will try to get a live-disk of Windows or get it on an old hard drive installed and work on it. Thanks for the help, mate!

Comment: Maybe you can make and use a drive with Windows PE (preinstallation environment). Good luck :-)